# ForEach Loop Iterates Twice Instead Of Once - Powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

Once again I have broken a foreach loop and cannot figure out why. It appears to iterate twice instead of once for **some** of the accounts. I think I have my {} in the correct format but apparently not.  Can anyone help me find what I'm missing?

Relevant Code:

```
foreach ($OU in $OUs) {

    # Search for User and/or Computer Objects inactive for XX days.  Disable object if not in DoNotDisable Security Groups
    $days = $days + "D"
    $accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]7D) @scope
    foreach($account in $accounts){
        If ($noDisable -notcontains $account.Name) {
            Write-Host $account
    #        #Disable-ADAccount -Identity $account.DistinguishedName -Verbose $whatIf | Export-Csv $logFile
       }
    }
}
```

Output:  Each computer account is listed twice **except** the last 2.

[image]

Comment: None of your output lines are exact duplicates, so I don't understand why you think your code is running twice.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Matthew Please see the output screenshot.  Each computer account is listed twice instead of once except for the last 2.

Comment: @poisedforlight I would try loading the script in PowerShell ISE and stepping through the code one line at a time.  This will certainly show you what your code is doing and why.

Comment: Add `-SearchScope OneLevel` to the `Search-ADAccount` command

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your directory tree looks like this:

```
NC root
 |- TopLevelOU
     |- SubOU
     |   |- Computer1
     |   |- Computer2
     |- Computer3
     |- Computer4
```

... and you start by querying for all `OU`s, and then search (recursively) through each one, you're going to get every object under `SubOU` *twice* - once from searching through the `TopLevelOU`, and once more from searching directly against `SubOU`.

Add `-SearchScope OneLevel` to your `Search-ADAccount` invocation if you want to contain each search to the immediate children of the target OU:

```
$accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]7D) @scope
```

Comment: Your explanation is very much appreciated.  That got me what I needed and more importantly I now understand why it wasn't working